# Why does the sky look like it has three suns in this video?

Tags: the-sun, optics

Check out [@natalie9280’s Tweet](https://twitter.com/natalie9280/status/1028400052924903424):

> long story short, friday morning at around 6:40am i looked outside and i saw three suns.
>   i checked to see if there was an eclipse and i could[n't] find anything.
>   twitter help pls
>
> [VIDEO: three progressively brighter "suns," left to right in a closely spaced row]

Comment: Maybe you should ask in Photography.SE?

Comment: Maybe the Moon, the Sun and a lamp?

Comment: We should not have to go elsewhere to see what the question is. Please [edit] the question, put some screenshots in (and keep the link for background).

Comment: Props for posting a hilarious tweet.    "I hope the government doesn't come after me for this",    I think it's a fair question if an optical illusion like that is possible or if it's 100% fake.   I think that's a fair question.

Comment: I'll post one real and one conspiracy.   Believe whichever you like:   real:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun_dog  conspiracy:  https://www.mirror.co.uk/science/nasa-cover-up-astronomer-claims-8123857

Answer (score 5):

The ghost images in the video resemble the Sun and are separated by only 2 or 3 degrees (4-6 Sun widths), so we can rule out atmospheric phenomena.
[Sun dogs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun_dog) or parhelia have shapes different from the Sun and appear 22 degrees away from it.

The effect is more likely due to looking through a double-paned window at an oblique angle.
The bright image on the right is the Sun viewed directly.
The image in the middle is a reflection by the inner glass surfaces facing each other, offset due to the gap width and the viewing angle.
The faint image on the left is a further reflection of the middle image.